# Creating folder in ftp server

Tags: vba, vbscript, ftp, scheduled-tasks

I have a vbscript file as you see below:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSB = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")

yesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
folderName = sprintf("{0:yyyyMMdd}", Array(yesterday)) & ".opentrades"

fullPath = "C:\test\" & folderName

Call FTPUpload(fullPath, folderName)

Sub FTPUpload(fullPath, folderName)
    Const copyType = 16
    waitTime = 80000
    FTPUser = "Username"
    FTPPass = "Password"
    FTPHost = "HostName"
    FTPDir = "/1/"

    strFTP = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost & FTPDir
    Set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)

    'Upload all files in folder
    If objFSO.FolderExists(fullPath) Then
        Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(fullPath)
        Wscript.Echo "Uploading folder " & fullPath & " to " & strFTP
        objFTP.CopyHere objFolder.Items, copyType
    End If

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Wscript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Description
    End If

    'Wait for upload
    WScript.Sleep waitTime
End Sub

Function sprintf(sFmt, aData)
    objSB.AppendFormat_4 sFmt, (aData)
    sprintf = objSB.ToString()
    objSB.Length = 0
End Function
```

The script copies all the files in the specified directory (fullPath variable) to the target directory (FTPDir variable). But I want to create a new folder having a name stored in folderName variable in FTP server and copy the files to the newly created folder. I'm new to vbscript and open to any advices.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line `Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(fullPath)` with

`Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(objFso.GetParentFolderName(fullPath))`

and `objFTP.CopyHere objFolder.Items, copyType` with

`objFTP.CopyHere objFolder.ParseName(objFso.GetFileName(fullPath)), copyType`

then it should work.

With this, your local namespace will be the parent folder of `fullPath` and `folderName` will be the item to be copied to the remote directory.