# To create automatic datewise folder and move the file in it

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I am stuck in a situation where I would like to create an automatic date-wise folder on the **FTP account**. Also, it requires moving one to two files in an updated folder every day. i.e. If it is 28-Dec-22 then the automatic folder with the mentioned format below should be created and the file then should be moved to the updated date folder.

the format of the date will be like this

2023/01/01

This means on the FTP and on the root directory there will be a year folder then in the year folder there will be a month folder and in the month folder, there will be date-wise folders (month and date will folder will be two digits only.

At the start of next month, it requires creating an automatic month folder (within the year folder) and then the normal date folders will be created. that will be 2023/02/01 and so on.

[image: Example of Date wise folders]

I am using the code mentioned below to move the file from source to destination and it also creates the date-wise folder but in this code, it can only send the file to one selected destination and this cannot be moved into the updated date-wise folder.

```
Sub moveAllFilesInDateFolderIfNotExist()
 Dim DateFold As String, fileName As String, objFSO As Object
 Const sFolderPath As String = "E:\Uploading\Source"
 Const dFolderPath As String = "E:\Uploading\Destination"
 DateFold = dFolderPath & "\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") ' create the folder if it does not exist
 If Dir(DateFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir DateFold
 fileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "\*.*")
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
 Do While fileName <> ""
    If Not objFSO.FileExists(DateFold & "\" & fileName) Then
        Name sFolderPath & "\" & fileName As DateFold & "\" & fileName

    End If
    fileName = Dir
 Loop
End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me in this situation?

Comment: You are missing a backslash here `DateFold = dFolderPath & "" &`. It should be `DateFold = dFolderPath & "\" &`... Then, you are talking about three folders (Year\month\day) but try creating `"ddmmyyyy"` one. Don't you know how to create such subfolders in the year one?

Comment: @FaneDuru Good to see you. I am afraid i have no idea how to create automatic folders on FTP. Definitely the code represents a different type of date format whereas i have required. I need help in it

Comment: Then, why did you post that piece of code...? Anyhow, there are here some threads to inspire you. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498413/creating-folder-in-ftp-server), for instance. It is an answer for VBScript but you can use it with small modifications in VBA.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have copied the code and paste it into text file and then save it as .VBS file, i have entered the path where the files are available and then added FTP credentials, upon double clicking the VBS script it first displays msg as "Uploading Folder to Host" and when i click Okay it gives error of "OBJECT REQUIRED OBJFTP

Comment: 1. Mentioning an error description **without the code line where the error is raised** is useless... 2. Did you change the initial code **as suggested in the accepted answer**?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes i have changed the code suggested in accepted answer,

Comment: @FaneDuru It says Line 27...... char:  9....... Error: Object Required: objFTP...... code: 800A01A8...... source: Microsoft VBscript Runtime Error

Comment: I am rather busy now, but I would try a quick connection. If you are available, please, send AnyD ID.

Comment: @FaneDuru I am leaving for some meetings, will be back after 3 hours. will send u a message